Does this set have an $\in$-minimal element?
This set has two elements, one of which is the empty set. The other element is an infinite descending chain. But this set seems to have an $\in$-minimal element (and so does its nonempty element)  so passes the requirement of foundation. And yet the infinite descending chain.

Can someone please clear up my confusion?

While this set in particular has an $\epsilon$-minimal element, the fact that it contains an infinite descending chain implies that some other set will not contain an $\epsilon$-minimal element. Specifically, the collection of sets which belong to the descending chain will have no $\epsilon$-minimal element.

Assuming that we're identifying the second member with the set itself, i.e. the set satisfies $a={\emptyset,a}$, ${a}$ is an example of a set with no $\in$-minimal element. (But in general, as Anon's answer indicates, going from an infinite descending sequence $x_n$ to a set with no $\in$-minimal element requires we collect the $x_n$ into a set... this highlights that the axiom of infinity plays a role here, in the sense that without it we can have an infinitely descending class sequence while still satisfying "every set has an $\in$-minimal element".)

There are a few equivalent versions of the axiom of foundation. One version states that every nonempty set contains an $\epsilon$-minimal element. The other says that there does not exist an infinite descending sequence of sets $x_1\ni x_2\ni\cdots$.
Without assuming the axiom of foundation, however, the claim that a specific set $X$ contains an $\epsilon$-minimal element is not equivalent to the claim that there does not exists an infinite descending chain of sets beginning with $X$, as your example demonstrates. I recommend taking a look at the proof of the equivalence between the two versions of the axiom of foundation. You will notice that given an infinite descending chain $x_1\ni x_2\ni\cdots$, we let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$. Then $X$ will have no $\epsilon$-minimal element, even though each of the sets $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ may contain an $\epsilon$-minimal element.

Thank you and I get it now. I wasn't saying that just because this set has an $\epsilon$-minimal element then foundation holds. Now I see that you can construct a set from this one and that set doesn't have an $\epsilon$-minimal element.
